# How to pass through a proxy server in c# using the windows azure marketplace bing api

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, bing-api

I am working on a school project where I am required to search the web with a particular search string and return the urls of webpages where the search string were found. I am using the bing api Windows azure marketplace. But the problem is my school uses a proxy server that requires a username and password. I have valid credentials but i don't know have to bypass the proxy server programmatically using c#. 
Could I please get a sample of how to connect to the bing api through a proxy server?

NB: Here is a sample of what i already have in c#

```
static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            try
            {

            const string bingkey = "my id";

            bing.Credentials = new NetworkCredential(bingkey, bingkey);

            var results = SearchAsync("search string");

           // IWebProxy proxy2 = HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy;

            int i =0; 

            foreach (var result in results.Result)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(result.Url);
                ++i; 
            }

            Console.WriteLine(i);
        }
        catch (WebException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        catch (DataServiceClientException e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(e.ToString());
        }

        Console.ReadKey(); 
    }

    public async static Task<IEnumerable<WebResult>> SearchAsync(string query)
    {
        DataServiceQuery<WebResult> webquery = bing.Web(query, null, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        var results = await Task.Factory.FromAsync(webquery.BeginExecute(null, null), asyncResult => webquery.EndExecute(asyncResult));
        return results;
    }
```

Comment: Just for clarification, because "bypass the proxy" could be misread as having malicious intent - you mean you don't know how to programatically authenticate (log in) to the proxy right?

Comment: @squillman Yes, I dont know how to programmatically log in to the proxy server to perform my bing search. Thanks for the correction

Comment: Have you tried setting `HttpWebRequest.DefaultWebProxy.Credentials` to your proxy username/password?

Comment: @Stephen Cleary. Yeah i did but still didn't work. Found a way around it though. I'll probably upload what i did soon.